# Is there any SDK for Reading and Writing IFC files in iOS?

Tags: ios, 3d, ifc

I want to view 3D view of buildings(IFC) in my iOS application. I have came across few library such as `IFCplusplus`, `ifcopenShell`, xBIM tool,but those don't have any instruction on how to use it on iOS, can anyone help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has [opened .NET to iOS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn771552.aspx#AndroidHTML) this year so xBIM might be interesting for you. We just created a new [website](https://xbimteam.github.io/index.html) to get started. You can use xBIM Geometry Engine to process the geometry into triangulated mesh and than render it in your application.